# Determine whether table is registered in geodatabase with ArcObjects

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, esri-geodatabase

In ArcCatalog we can register a table in the GeoDatabase using the tables context menu. Now i'm trying to find a way with ArcObjects, to detect whether an ITable is already registered, is this even possible?

I'm aware that registered tables are listed in the `GDB_ITEMS` system table, but some SDE connections do not have read access to this table, or only with a different (unknown) qualifier. So reading the system table directly is not an option in this case.

Comment: I assume if it IS an `IFeatureClass` or an `IObjectClass` the table already is registered. I´m not sure if this also applies to `ITable`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - You are right, an IFeatureClass is always registered. So the question should be about `ITable` objects, in a test i found out, that it is possible to do a successful QueryInterface to `IObjectClass` even if the table is not registered.

Comment: Really? Oooh, and what happens if you query the interface for `ITable`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere - The test lists all datasets of the workspace. The unregistered `IDataset` is a standalone table and can then be query-interfaced to `ITable` as well as to `IObjectClass` and others like `IClass`, `IClassEx`, `IClassID`, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, with a bit of luck, i found the answer myself. There is an interface IFeatureWorkspaceManage which is supported by feature workspaces, and there we can ask for this information.

```
IDataset dataset = ...;
IFeatureWorkspaceManage workspaceManage = dataset.Workspace as IFeatureWorkspaceManage;
bool isRegistered = false;
if (workspaceManage != null)
  isRegistered = workspaceManage.IsRegisteredAsObjectClass(dataset.Name);
```

To register an unregistered table we can use:

```
IClassSchemaEdit.RegisterAsObjectClass()
```

Comment: Nice, did not know of this.

Comment: @martinstoeckli, please mark this as answer.